# Watin. Browser unexplainably closes after opening

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, internet-explorer, watin

Below is the code...

```
using (var browser = new IE(URL))
{
   Element element = browser.Element(Find.ByName("txtFirstName"));
}
```

I'm getting this error message in the Debugger when I inspect the Element object:

> Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.

I've reinstalled VS2010 and that didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly _when_ is it the browser closes/you get the error message? Because when you create your browser object in the using block, that object will be disposed as soon as that block has finished executing (which in your case means straight after the line `Element element = browser.Element(Find.ByName("txtFirstName"));`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have two lines, the "previous function evaluation" that is timing out is Internet Explorer.  Reinstall Internet Explorer, and ensure that you are running it with the correct permissions.  I suspect your computer is shared. You need administrator privileges to run this kind of code.

Hope reinstalling Internet Explorer helps. Good luck!  Let me know how you get on.